# ClassCastException when trying to extend XYLineAndShapeRenderer (JFreeChart)

Tags: jfreechart, classcastexception

Im trying to override the `getItemPaint()` method of `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` by creating a subclass:

```
private class MultiRenderer extends XYLineAndShapeRenderer{
        @Override
        public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int column) {
            if(row==2){
                float x = getAmplitude()[column];
                return floatToColor(x);
            }
            return super.getItemPaint(row, column);
        }
        private Color floatToColor(float val){...}
}
```

And calling:

```
XYPlot xyPlot = (XYPlot) myJFreeChartObject.getPlot();
MultiRenderer r = (MultiRenderer) xyPlot.getRenderer();
```

But im getting a `ClassCastException`. **Is there a way I can cast this properly or override `getItemPaint` without creating a subclass**? Im trying to plot 2 series as regular line plots and a 3rd series without a line and different color points. The first 2 series should have a line but no point markers.

*Note `getAmplitude()` just returns an array of floats between 0 and 1*

Comment: In your example I can't see `xyPlot .setRenderer(new MultiRenderer());` can you prived a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use an [Anonymous Inner Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

```java
plot.setRenderer(new XYLineAndShapeRenderer() {          

  @Override
  public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int column) {
    if(row==2){
      float x = getAmplitude()[column];
      return floatToColor(x);
    }
    return super.getItemPaint(row, column);
 }

private Color floatToColor(float val){...}
```

});

Or use a [`DrawingSupplier`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/class-use/DrawingSupplier.html) for your [`plot`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/Plot.html#setDrawingSupplier%28org.jfree.chart.plot.DrawingSupplier%29)